# Contextual typing in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Snippet:

```
class A {
    x: number;
}

class B extends A {
    y: number;
}

var f1: { (y: A): void } | { (y: B): void };
f1 = (y)=>{} // y :any

var f2: { (x: number): (y: A) => void } | { (x: number): (y: B) => void };
f2 = ((x) => { return (y)=>{}; }); //y :A
```

Why when the arrow function are contextually typed by the `f1` the `y` parameter has the `any` type but in the case of the `f2` the `y` parameter has the `A` type?

Comment: This is difficult to answer without really looking into the source, but in either way there are better ways to type `f1` and `f2`. For `f1`: `var f1: (y: A | B) => void`

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a contextual type is a *union* of potential signatures, all of those signatures must be completely identical. That includes the parameter types.

The reason is that it's ambiguous as to what you potentially wanted. You could imagine logic to say "union the parameters of all signatures that the function could satisfy", but the work hasn't yet been done.

As a sort of reference, here's the part in our source code that covers it:

```
function getContextualSignature(node: FunctionExpression | ArrowFunction | MethodDeclaration): Signature {
    Debug.assert(node.kind !== SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration || isObjectLiteralMethod(node));
    const type = getContextualTypeForFunctionLikeDeclaration(node);
    if (!type) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if (!(type.flags & TypeFlags.Union)) {
        return getNonGenericSignature(type, node);
    }
    let signatureList: Signature[];
    const types = (<UnionType>type).types;
    for (const current of types) {
        const signature = getNonGenericSignature(current, node);
        if (signature) {
            if (!signatureList) {
                // This signature will contribute to contextual union signature
                signatureList = [signature];
            }
            else if (!compareSignaturesIdentical(signatureList[0], signature, /*partialMatch*/ false, /*ignoreThisTypes*/ true, /*ignoreReturnTypes*/ true, compareTypesIdentical)) {
                // Signatures aren't identical, do not use
                return undefined;
            }
            else {
                // Use this signature for contextual union signature
                signatureList.push(signature);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's nice to see you at stackoverflow, thanks. The code you have referred is used for arrow function which are contextually typed by `f1`. The rules you have mentioned *(contextual type is a union of potential signatures, all of those signatures must be completely identical)* from spec are applied for `f1`. But in the case of `f2` return expression statement (arrow function) are contextually typed by  `{(y: A) => void}|{(y: B) => void}` the same type as in the case `f1` but typescript makes reduction of the union applying `getUnionType` and resulting contextual type is `{(y:A):void}`, why?

Comment: The same contextual type is in both cases but in the first place *tsc* compares for parameter equivalence in the second makes reduction using `getUnionType`, this is a real question, why does typescript apply different strategies to at first glance the same cases?